# How to split a component when it gets big. ReactJs

Tags: reactjs, laravel

I have just started learning ReactJs and I am using it in laravel project for practice.

Everything is going okay, but what I dont like is that my component is getting bigger. I can not think of an optimal way to split it in several, simpler files like .js and .jsx..

Here is the [component](https://github.com/Nika-Simonishvili/sql-ex/blob/main/resources/js/components/index.js) and I will appreciate any corrections and recommendations.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on the Code Review Stack Exchange.

Comment: @AKX the question as it stands is totally unsuited to [codereview.se], because it includes neither the code nor any statement of its purpose. You should have pointed the asker at [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5778), as some things are done differently over there - e.g. we need a good description of the *purpose* of the code to give context, and question titles should simply say what the code *does* (the question is always, "_How can I improve this?_").  It's important that the code works correctly; include the unit tests if possible.

Comment: @TobySpeight Even if the current formatting isn't good for CR, it still belongs more there than here, since there is no one single correct solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like I Split your code I create a new Component of a new question modal and pass value through props. So you can split like this. I try only one but you can split all three modal.
You can think as it also [click](https://beta.reactjs.org/images/docs/s_thinking-in-react_ui_outline.png)

```
const NewQuestionModal = ({isOpen, close, titleValue, solutionValue, onAddQuestion, onTitleChange, onSolutionChange  }) => {
        return(<Modal isOpen={isOpen} toggle={close}>
        <ModalHeader toggle={close}>Add a new question</ModalHeader>
        <ModalBody>
    
            <FormGroup>
                <Label for="title">Question</Label>
                <Input id="title"
                        value={titleValue}
                        onChange={onTitleChange}
                >sda</Input>
            </FormGroup>
    
            <FormGroup>
                <Label for="solution">Solution</Label>
                <Input id="solution"
                       value={solutionValue}
                       onChange={onSolutionChange}
                >sda</Input>
            </FormGroup>
    
        </ModalBody>
        <ModalFooter>
            <Button color="primary" onClick={onAddQuestion}>Add question</Button>{' '}
            <Button color="secondary" onClick={close}>Cancel</Button>
        </ModalFooter>
    </Modal>)
    }
    
    <div className="App container">
                    <h1>Question list </h1>
                    <Button color="primary" onClick={this.toggleNewQuestionModal.bind(this)}>Add question</Button>
               {/*================New Question Modal==============*/}
                    <NewQuestionModal 
                    isOpen={this.state.newQuestionModal}
                    close={this.toggleNewQuestionModal.bind(this)}
                    titleValue={this.state.newQuestionData.title}
                    onTitleChange={(e) => {
                        let {newQuestionData} = this.state
                        newQuestionData.title = e.target.value
                        this.setState({newQuestionData} )
                    }}
                    solutionValue={this.state.newQuestionData.solution}
                    onSolutionChange={(e) => {
                        let {newQuestionData} = this.state
                        newQuestionData.solution = e.target.value
                        this.setState({newQuestionData} )
                    }}
                    onAddQuestion={this.addQuestion.bind(this)}
                    />
    
                    <Modal isOpen={this.state.editQuestionModal} toggle={this.toggleEditQuestionModal.bind(this)}>
                        <ModalHeader toggle={this.toggleEditQuestionModal.bind(this)}>Edit question</ModalHeader>
                        <ModalBody>
    
                            <FormGroup>
                                <Label for="title">Question</Label>
                                <Input id="title"
                                       value={this.state.editQuestionData.title}
                                       onChange={(e) => {
                                           let {editQuestionData} = this.state
                                           editQuestionData.title = e.target.value
                                           this.setState({editQuestionData} )
                                       }}
                                >sda</Input>
                            </FormGroup>
    
                            <FormGroup>
                                <Label for="solution">Solution</Label>
                                <Input id="solution"
                                       value={this.state.editQuestionData.solution}
                                       onChange={(e) => {
                                           let {editQuestionData} = this.state
                                           editQuestionData.solution = e.target.value
                                           this.setState({editQuestionData} )
                                       }}
                                >sda</Input>
                            </FormGroup>
    
                        </ModalBody>
                        <ModalFooter>
                            <Button color="primary" onClick={this.updateQuestion.bind(this)}>Update question</Button>{' '}
                            <Button color="secondary" onClick={this.toggleEditQuestionModal.bind(this)}>Cancel</Button>
                        </ModalFooter>
                    </Modal>
    
                    <Modal isOpen={this.state.isOpen} toggle={this.toggleModal.bind(this.id)}>
                        <ModalHeader toggle={this.toggleModal.bind(this)}  className="btn-primary">Query result</ModalHeader>
                        <Table className="table">
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>data:</th><td>{this.state.solutionData.data}</td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </Table>
                        <ModalFooter>
                            <Button color="secondary" onClick={this.toggleModal.bind(this)}>Cancel</Button>
                        </ModalFooter>
                    </Modal>
    
    
                    <Table>
                        <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>#</th>
                            <th>Question</th>
                            <th>Solution</th>
                            <th>Actions</th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        {questions}
                        </tbody>
                    </Table>
                </div>
```